# List All the countries in a specific language

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need to list all the countries in the French Language.

```
all_countries = self.env['res.country'].search([])
for country in all_countries:
   _logger.error(country.name)
```

With this code i get the Country English Name.How to get the French one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no reference between country and languages. You have to get the list by external modules. Try [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/), get the list of country code (by language code fr-*), then search for matches in res.country.

Or you can override res.country and add language reference your self :)